# Docker, run container as non-root user and enable SSH connection

Tags: linux, docker, ssh

I am running a Docker container on a remote server, and I need to:

- connect to this container from my local machine through SSH (actually, I need this to debug remotely using VS Code);
- run the container as non-root user, so that the files created from within the container are still editable/removable when I log into the remote machine with my normal user;

I've been following various tutorials I found online, and so far I am using this Dockerfile:

```
# create and switch to non-root user 
ARG UID
ARG GID

# Update the package list, install sudo, create a non-root user, and grant password-less sudo permissions
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y sudo && \
    addgroup --gid $GID docker_user && \
    adduser --uid $UID --gid $GID --disabled-password --gecos "" docker_user && \
    echo 'docker_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

# Create ssh directory in home for non-root user
RUN mkdir -p /home/docker_user/.ssh
# Copy the ssh public key in the authorized_keys file.
COPY rsa_key.pub /home/docker_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
# change ownership of the key file.
RUN chown -R docker_user:$GID /home/docker_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/docker_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 600 /home/docker_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
# authorize SSH connection with root account
RUN echo "PermitRootLogin yes" > /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# change password root
RUN echo "docker_user:docker"|chpasswd
# Expose docker port 22
EXPOSE 22

# Set the non-root user as the default user
USER docker_user
```

and building the image by:

```
docker build --build-arg UID=$(id -u) --build-arg GID=$(id -g) -t image_name .
```

But I'm having some issues.

1. First, I tried mounting the whole home folder of my user on the local machine to the home folder of the user in the docker container:

```
docker run --name container_name -it -d --rm -v /home/local_user_name/:/home/docker_user/ image_name
```

In this case, I can create files in the container, which are then found in the home of local_user_name on the host machine. However, if I try to SSH into the container, I get the error:

```
ssh docker_ip_address
-bash: exec: : not found
Connection to docker_ip_address closed.
```

2. I tried mounting folders in /home separately:

```
docker run --name container_name -it --rm -v /home/local_user_name/.vscode-server:/home/docker_user/.vscode-server -v /home/local_user_name/work/projects:/home/docker_user/work/projects -v /home/local_user_name/work/data:/home/docker_user/work/data image_name
```

In this case, the SSH connection works fine, but I have permission errors when the code in the container tries to access some files in the subfolders of the mounted folders. Do you know how I can fix this?